# Using WF Rules without using workflow activities or the embedded rule set editor

Tags: rules, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

Has any one used WF Rules engine outside workflow activities WITHOUT using Rules Editor or CodeDOM?

**Scenario**

I am trying to use the Rule engine that ships with Workflow foundation classes with .Net Framework for a web based application. We evaluate hundreds of Validation Rules before proceeding towards a calculation engine for a complex calculation.

I have gone through many blogs which state how to use Rules engine without having to have Workflow Activities including https://github.com/geersch/WorkflowRulesEngine.
However they all eventually end up using a Rule Set Editor for defining rules. I want to declaratively define rules in an XML file

**What I am looking for**

1. I need to be able to specify Rules in simple XML without dealing with CODEDOM. CodeDOM seems to be very complex to write.
2. I should not be dependent on RuleSet Editor for defining rules.

Any thoughts any one ?

Comment: What version of WF are you using ?

Comment: Jayantha, We are using .Net 4.0 for the application and WF4 (v4.0.30319) for Workflow classes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what kind of rules you are evaluating, but if you search a good open source rule engine, [here is one](http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Thanks David. We would like to minimize any external dependencies. From what I have seen, WF rules execute fairly quickly, its only the definition process that seems painful. Wish Microsot was less obsessed with GUI based approach for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article for a strategy (not a solution) to approach the problem.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Rules-Using-the-23c5d561

Answer (score 0):

The serialization format for WF Rules is CodeDom.

It does not have another serialization format built-in.

If you want an alternate XML representation, you would need to create a tool to map between the representations.